# warning : Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs

Tags: r

I used the following for converting time in a standard form:

```
    dg1<-df2 %>% mutate(arr = hms(hours = ARR_HR, minutes = ARR_MIN))
```

but in one of my code I keep getting this warning:

```
    In .parse_hms(..., order = "HM", quiet = quiet) :
   Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs
```

do you know how I can fix it? I believe it is about time format. I was trying to replace time of some rows in other rows. it gives me NA instead of replacing time

Answer (score 1):

`hms` is a function common in `lubridate` and `hms` package.  If we load both package, and if the lubridate one masks the other one, it can occur.  In such cases, explicitly specify the package with `::`

```
hms::hms(hours = 12, minutes = 24)
#12:24:00
```

Creating a reproducible example with `dplyr`

```
df2 <- data.frame(ARR_HR = c(1, 10), ARR_MIN = c(32, 42))
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
     mutate(arr = hms::hms(hours = ARR_HR, minutes = ARR_MIN))
#  ARR_HR ARR_MIN      arr
#1      1      32 01:32:00
#2     10      42 10:42:00
```

---

With `lubridate` loaded, it can result in

```
hms(hours = 12, minutes = 24)
#[1] NA NA
```

> Warning message: In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
>   Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs

Comment: I fixed the problem with: dg1$arr<- paste(substr(dg1$arr, 1, 2), substr(dg1$arr, 3, 4))

Comment: @shere Okay., so you used `paste`., but if you want to have a time object, still needs `hms`